# Data Table search is giving error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm getting a warning saying requested unknown parameter, and after I press ok the **search** is not working correctly.

[image]

any solution for this

> DataTable warning .......... Requested unknown parameter

Please find how i created the table

```html
<table class="dataTable border bordered striped" data-role="datatable" data-auto-width="false" id="brandTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 20px">
      </td>
      <td class="sortable-column sort-asc">ID</td>
      <td class="sortable-column">Brand Name</td>
      <td class="sortable-column">Account Manager</td>
      <td class="sortable-column">Date Updated</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php foreach ($fw->customer($_SESSION['USERID'])->getAllBrands() as $v) { ?>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label class="input-control checkbox small-check no-margin">
          <input type="checkbox">
          <span class="check"></span>
        </label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <?php echo $v['id']; ?>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="updateBrands.html?id=<?php echo $v['id']; ?>">
          <?php echo $v['brandName']; ?>
        </a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <?php echo $fw->customer($_SESSION['USERID'])->getAccountManagerbyId($v['accountManager_id']); ?></td>
      <td>
        <?php echo $v['dateCreated']; ?>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an undefined or null value at 3 column of 35 row. You should pass some value at that place .